# How to do animation in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, animation, canvas, requestanimationframe

Hi guys,

My assignment requires me to draw faces using JavaScript and then press buttons to change the face on the canvas. It also requires me to do an animation between the faces. I looked around and noticed that I need to use requestAnimationFrame but don't understand how to do also. Also, how do I do it in such a way that the code is not messy? Thanks in advance guys.

```
        //Neutral/Smiling Face
        context.beginPath();
            context.fillStyle = "rgb(255,255,0)" //Drawing the face in yellow colour
            context.lineWidth = 3;
            context.arc(300,300,200,0,Math.PI*4,true);
            context.fill();
        context.stroke();
        //Left Eyebrow
        context.save();
        context.translate(240,180);
        context.rotate(20*Math.PI/180);
        context.beginPath();
            context.fillStyle = "rgb(0,0,0)";
            context.rect(-45,-8,90,16);
            context.fill();
            context.restore();
        context.stroke();
        //Right Eyebrow
        context.save();
        context.translate(360,180)
        context.rotate(-20*Math.PI/180);
        context.beginPath();
            context.fillStyle = "rgb(0,0,0)";
            context.rect(-45,-8,90,16);
            context.fill();
            context.restore();
        context.stroke();
        //Black Pupils of the Eyes
        context.beginPath();
            context.fillStyle = "rgb(0,0,0)";
            context.moveTo(255,250); //LeftEye
            context.arc(220,250,40,0,Math.PI*4,true);
            context.moveTo(415,250);//RightEye
            context.arc(380,250,40,0,Math.PI*4,true);
            context.fill();
        context.stroke();
        //White Inner Eyes
        context.beginPath();
            context.fillStyle = "rgb(255,255,255)";
                context.moveTo(240,250); //LeftPupil
                context.arc(220,250,15,0,Math.PI*4,true);
                context.moveTo(400,250);//RightPupil
                context.arc(380,250,15,0,Math.PI*4,true);
            context.fill();
        context.stroke();
        //Nose
        context.beginPath();
        context.fillStyle = "rgb(0,0,0)";
            context.moveTo(300,275);
            context.lineTo(275,325);
            context.lineTo(325,325);
        context.fill();
        context.closePath();
        context.stroke();
        //Mouth
        context.beginPath();
            context.fillStyle = "rgb(0,0,0)";
            context.lineWidth = 1;
            context.moveTo(300,350);
            context.arc(300,350,100,0,Math.PI,false);
            context.fill();
        context.stroke();


        function sadFace() {
        //Drawing the sad face
        context.beginPath();
            context.fillStyle = "rgb(255,255,0)" //Drawing the face in yellow colour
            context.lineWidth = 3;
            context.arc(300,300,200,0,Math.PI*4,true);
            context.fill();
        context.stroke();
        //Left Eyebrow
        context.save();
        context.translate(200,180);
        context.rotate(-20*Math.PI/180);
        context.beginPath();
            context.fillStyle = "rgb(0,0,0)";
            context.rect(-45,-8,90,16);
            context.fill();
            context.restore();
        context.stroke();
        //Right Eyebrow
        context.save();
        context.translate(400,180)
        context.rotate(20*Math.PI/180);
        context.beginPath();
            context.fillStyle = "rgb(0,0,0)";
            context.rect(-45,-8,90,16);
            context.fill();
            context.restore();
        context.stroke();
        //Black Pupils of the Eyes
        context.beginPath();
            context.fillStyle = "rgb(0,0,0)";
            context.moveTo(255,250); //LeftEye
            context.arc(220,250,40,0,Math.PI*4,true);
            context.moveTo(415,250);//RightEye
            context.arc(380,250,40,0,Math.PI*4,true);
            context.fill();
        context.stroke();
        //White Inner Eyes
        context.beginPath();
            context.fillStyle = "rgb(255,255,255)";
            context.moveTo(240,250); //LeftPupil
            context.arc(220,250,15,0,Math.PI*4,true);
            context.moveTo(400,250);//RightPupil
            context.arc(380,250,15,0,Math.PI*4,true);
            context.fill();
        context.stroke();
        //Nose
        context.beginPath();
        context.fillStyle = "rgb(0,0,0)";
            context.moveTo(300,275);
            context.lineTo(275,325);
            context.lineTo(325,325);
        context.fill();
        context.closePath();
        context.stroke();
        //Mouth
        context.beginPath();
            context.fillStyle = "rgb(0,0,0)";
            context.lineWidth = 1;
            context.moveTo(305,427);
            context.arc(305,427,80,0,Math.PI,true);
            context.fill();
        context.stroke();
        }


        var angryButton = document.getElementById("angryFace");
        var sadButton = document.getElementById("sadFace");
        var surprisedButton = document.getElementById("surprisedFace");
        var neutralButton = document.getElementById("neutralFace");

        sadButton.addEventListener("click", sadFace);
        angryButton.addEventListener("click", angryFace);
        surprisedButton.addEventListener("click", surprisedFace);
        neutralButton.addEventListener("click", neutralFace);
```